# Using the rules inside a locale (group) Isabelle

Tags: isabelle

Assume I have the following theorem:

```
comm_group ⦇carrier = e_aff, mult = add, one = (1, 0)⦈
```

and I want to show that:

```
add (add (x1,y1) (x2,y2)) (i (x2,y2)) = (x1,y1)
```

where `i` is the inverse operation of the group. This `obviously` holds in a group. How can I extract this knowledge from the assumption?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `comm_group …` is the locale predicate, i.e. the thing that shows that you actually have an instance of the locale. To actually use it, one typically *interprets* the locale:

```
interpret comm_group "⦇carrier = e_aff, mult = add, one = (1, 0)⦈"
  by (fact <insert your theorem here>)
```

After this, all the theorems proven in the context of the `comm_group` locale become available to you (e.g. `m_assoc`). You can optionally add a prefix to those names (particularly useful if there are name clashes, especially when you have several interpretations of the same locale):

```
interpret G: comm_group "⦇carrier = e_aff, mult = add, one = (1, 0)⦈"
  by (fact <insert your theorem here>)
```

Then the theorem would be called `G.m_assoc`. This is covered in Section 5 of the [locale tutorial](https://isabelle.in.tum.de/dist/Isabelle2019/doc/locales.pdf).

By the way, you may want to consider introducing an abbreviation for your group, e.g.

```
define G where "G = ⦇carrier = e_aff, mult = add, one = (1, 0)⦈"
```

to make writing down statements about it less cumbersome. You can also make Isabelle's simplifier unfold that definition automatically by doing

```
define G where [simp]: "G = ⦇carrier = e_aff, mult = add, one = (1, 0)⦈"
```